# needed to write excel function to loop thru all sheet in workbook then return all value in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

This function should pick ticket number from main sheet then look for the status of the same ticket in all other sheets. Then update all status in a cell for same ticket from different sheet in main sheet. So far i wrote below code but don't work

```vb
Function SingleCellExtract(Lookupvalue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Result As String
    Dim sheets As Variant
    Dim sheet As Variant

    sheets = Array("Multiple Values single cell VL", "Sheet2")
    For Each sheet In sheets
        For i = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
            If LookupRange.Cells(i, 1) = Lookupvalue Then
                Result = Result & " " & LookupRange.Cells(i, ColumnNumber) & ","
            End If
        Next i
    Next sheet

    SingleCellExtract = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a Range into a function, that range referes to a specific range on a specific sheet.

In your code, you loop over an array of sheet names but don't do anything with that name.

Your code, refactored

```vb
Function SingleCellExtract(Lookupvalue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Result As String
    Dim sheets As Variant
    Dim sheet As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SheetLookupRange As Range
    
    sheets = Array("Multiple Values single cell VL", "Sheet2")
    For Each sheet In sheets
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet) '<~~ reference to the looped sheet
        Set SheetLookupRange = ws.Range(LookupRange.Address) '<~~ reference to the range on on the looped sheet
        For i = 1 To SheetLookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
            If SheetLookupRange.Cells(i, 1) = Lookupvalue Then
                Result = Result & " " & SheetLookupRange.Cells(i, ColumnNumber) & ","
            End If
        Next i
    Next sheet

    SingleCellExtract = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: It worked.
Do you suggest any book/document ( pdf ) on writing functions ? Thank you for your help.